# Group by multidimensional array and count values

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I have array like this

```
[
    (int) 0 => [
        'Servloc' => '1',
        'WasteText' => 'Container1',
        'ContainerText' => 'Container Type 1',
        'ContainerCount' => (int) 5,
    ],
    (int) 1 => [
        'Servloc' => '1',
        'WasteText' => 'Container1',
        'ContainerText' => 'Container Type 1',
        'ContainerCount' => (int) 4,
    ],
    (int) 2 => [
        'Servloc' => '1',
        'WasteText' => 'Container1',
        'ContainerText' => 'Container Type 1',
        'ContainerCount' => (int) 3,
    ],
    (int) 3 => [
        'Servloc' => '1',
        'WasteText' => 'Container2',
        'ContainerText' => 'Container Type 1',
        'ContainerCount' => (int) 3,
    ],
    (int) 4 => [
        'Servloc' => '2',
        'WasteText' => 'Container1',
        'ContainerText' => 'Container Type 2',
        'ContainerCount' => (int) 1,
    ],  
]
```

I need to group this array based on same values of Servloc, WasteText, ContainerText PLUS SUM all values from ContainerCount.

So result for this array should be:

```
[
    (int) 0 => [
        'Servloc' => '1',
        'WasteText' => 'Container1',
        'ContainerText' => 'Container Type 1',
        'ContainerCount' => (int) 12,
    ],
    (int) 3 => [
        'Servloc' => '1',
        'WasteText' => 'Container2',
        'ContainerText' => 'Container Type 1',
        'ContainerCount' => (int) 3,
    ],
    (int) 4 => [
        'Servloc' => '2',
        'WasteText' => 'Container1',
        'ContainerText' => 'Container Type 2',
        'ContainerCount' => (int) 1,
    ],  
]
```

I have tried to foreach first array twice and compare those values, if they are same then put in another array as result. But it doesnt work....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
function groupArray($data) {
    $keys = array();

    foreach ($data as $child) {
        $key = $child['Servloc'] . $child['WasteText'] . $child['ContainerText'];

        if(!array_key_exists($key, $keys)) {
            // check if we already found objects with the same data, if not then we start with 0 as containercount
            $keys[$key] = array(
                'Servloc' => $child['Servloc'],
                'WasteText' => $child['WasteText'],
                'ContainerText' => $child['ContainerText'],
                'ContainerCount' => 0,
            );
        }

        $keys[$key]['ContainerCount'] += $child['ContainerCount'];
    }

    return array_values($keys);
}
```